# Certain elements in for loop outputting differently

Tags: python

I have an array like this:

```
array=[['001', 'Playing Cards', '0.99', 2, 1.98], ['003', 'Keyboard', '12.99', 1, 12.99], 
['N/A', 'Unavailable', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A'], ['002', 'Notebook', '0.59', 4, 2.36]]
```

In my program, I have a for loop like this:

```
for subarray in array:
    for element in subarray:
        length=((20 if element==subarray[1] else 6)-(len(str(element))))
        if element != subarray[4]:
            print((element)," "*length,end=" ")
        else:
            print((element)," "*length)
```

If I were to run this, the program outputs:

```
001     Playing Cards         0.99    2       1.98   
003     Keyboard              12.99   1       12.99  
N/A    
Unavailable           N/A    
N/A    
N/A    
002     Notebook              0.59    4       2.36
```

What I want the program to output is:

```
001     Playing Cards         0.99    2       1.98   
003     Keyboard              12.99   1       12.99  
N/A     Unavailable           N/A     N/A     N/A
002     Notebook              0.59    4       2.36
```

No matter how I look at the code, I don't understand why the program is not outputting the sub array containing "unavailable" just like the rest, I have made sure that the structure of the array and the number of elements in each array are the same but for some reason it still outputs the "unavailable" part on a new line. I apologise if I haven't worded my question the best but I was wondering if anyone could spot what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: the problem lies in the line `if element != sub_array[4]:`. Note that in your `Unavailable` subarray, elements 0, 2, 3, and 4 are all identical.

Comment: You need to indent the body of the first `for` loop.

Comment: @Allan why did you delete pretty much the entire body of your question?

Answer (score 2):

When you check `element != sub_list[4]` it is not the same thing as "is this the element in index 4", since you have multiple `"N/A"` values in that row that are the same as the last one (therefore thinking it is the end of the row) Instead you can keep a count of which index you are on with `enumerate`:

```
for i,element in enumerate(sub_array):
    ...
    if i != 4: #check the index instead 
        ...
```

Or you could just break the lines after each inner for loop:

```
for subarray in array:
    for element in subarray:
        length=((20 if element==subarray[1] else 6)-(len(str(element))))
        print((element)," "*length,end=" ")
```

Note that the above uses a really hard to understand way of doing padding, this way might be a bit easier to understand:

```
for subarray in array:
    for element in subarray:
        if element == subarray[1]:
            padding = 20
        else:
            padding = 6
        print(str(element).ljust(padding), end=" ")
    print() #end of line
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error was `element != subarray[4]`. It's hier a string comparing.

In the list `['N/A', 'Unavailable', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A']` you have than problem with this condition.

I won't correct your codes. But i have another solution with string format
`{index:length}`

```
array = [['001', 'Playing Cards', '0.99', 2, 1.98], ['003', 'Keyboard', '12.99', 1, 12.99],
        ['N/A', 'Unavailable', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A'], ['002', 'Notebook', '0.59', 4, 2.36]]

for subarray in array:
    # i must convert all of elements to string, because the 4. and 5.   
    # elements are str in the 'Unavailable' list but int in other lists
    str_array = [str(element) for element in subarray]
    print("{0:6}{1:20}{2:6}{3:6}{4:6}".format(*str_array))
    # index could be ignored
    print("{:6}{:20}{:6}{:6}{:6}".format(*str_array))
```

Result:

```
001   Playing Cards       0.99  2     1.98  
003   Keyboard            12.99 1     12.99 
N/A   Unavailable         N/A   N/A   N/A   
002   Notebook            0.59  4     2.36
```